# How to obtain MGRS 100Km square id for every such square on world map?

Tags: data, mgrs

I'm trying to compile a list of MGRS 100km square identifiers for every such square (eg 4QFJ for Honolulu Hawaii); excluding the poles (85 to -85 latitudes). If possible it'd also be great to know which of these 100km squares intersect land.

Is there any way to compute this or is there a recommended data set to look at?

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try and do this?

Comment: I'm not using any gis software but I would be open to doing so. I was really hoping that there would just be a list of these values somewhere though @PolyGeo

Comment: If you are after data, rather than help with using GIS software, then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be worth looking at.  If you decide to ask there then be sure to check their Help to make sure that what you are asking is on-topic first.

Comment: Calculating MGRS squares from scratch is NOT something you want to do without GIS software.  I had the Esri Projection Engine to help, and it still look a great deal of effort to build what I needed. Part of the issue is that the tiles at the edges of UTM zones overlap.

Comment: Exactly @PolyGeo

Comment: This was answered in 90 minutes at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7355